# Как исправить проблему с материалами?

Tags: blender, unreal-engine-4

Я сделал модель в blender и решил перекинуть её в ue4 сохранив её в fbx. Онлайн редакторы её видят хорошо но не ue4
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот так видит ue4
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробывал сохранить в obj таже проблема с материалом. Как настроить ue4 чтобы он видел материал ?

Comment: Пробовали заходит в материалы и сохранять? Такое бывает время от времени, что он не прогружается

Comment: @votchezanick - пробывал ни помогает